# Measuring profit with GA Ecommerce tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics, web-analytics

We have implemented the Ecommerce tracking script from Google Universal Analytics and are currently sending revenue to GA when customers land on the order confirmation page.

We would like to also send data for profit of the transaction and the individual items ordered. We could just replace the actual revenue  with profit but we would like to have both listed in GA.

There is no documentation on how to do this client side (which is preferable for us) in the GA help pages. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#addItem

Comment: I guess you have got the answer as you posted the link. What do you mean by profit? Do you mean the margin? If so then you have to calculate the margin per item and send it to GA.

Comment: I know - and we can easily calculate this. But how do we send it? There is only 1 "revenue" in the script: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#addTrans

Comment: Have you tried to send an additional data in the script such as margin?

Comment: Actually you can upload the product margin as a csv file (sku or name as a key and margin as data to import) and the value will be automatically added to incoming product data.  Look for "data import" in the documentation (I think you need to enable enhanced e-commerce to use data import at product level).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - but we want to do it client side. Will we need to use custom dimensions/metrics for this?

Comment: @Klelund, you can pass a custom variable in product scope in your transaction tracking code, but do you really want to put your margins where people can see it (i.e. the source code of your page) ? I would have assumed that this is confidential information.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Yes, it is not a problem for us. We do some calculations before showing it in the source code, so it is not really useful for others. Should the custom variable be in the ecommerce tracking code (<script type="text/javascript">
    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {.....) 
or it the universal analytics tracking code?

Comment: This should go in your transaction code in the code for the individual items . If you want to pass it as a string you need a custom dimension, if you want GA to add it up automatically you need a custom metric (both would need to be in product scope).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Can I just add my own metrics/dimensions to the ('commerce:addItem', ?

Comment: Like this (check PROFIT):
ga('ecommerce:addItem', { 
'id': '1078047', 
'name': 'F-91W', 
'sku': 'F-91W', 
'category': 'Casio Watches', 
'price': '119', 
'PROFIT': 'XXX',
'quantity': '1'

Answer (score 0):

since the profit is money you need to use a product scoped custom metric.

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {      // a productFieldObject 
   'id': '1078047',            
   'name': 'F-91W', 
   'sku': 'F-91W',             // sku is not a part of productFieldObject 
   'category': 'Casio Watches', 
   'price': '119',
   'quantity': '1'
   'metric1': '20.5'          // add the profit custom metric
})

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail'); // or some other action
```